# How to insert correct values in database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, mysqli

I have a jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/58/

Please follow steps in fiddle:

1: When you open fiddle, click on "Add Question" button twice, this will append 2 rows.

2: In first row select answer buttons "A" and "C", in second row select answer buttons "A", "B" and "E". The text input values for each answer button selected is displayed underneath.

Now what I want to do is post the question number and the answer values into the database.

The database should look like this below when posted:

Question Table:

```
QuestionId (Question Number)
1
2
```

Answer Table:

```
AnswerId (auto)  QuestionId  Answer
1                1           A
2                1           C
3                2           A
4                2           B
5                2           E
```

What my question is that how do I post the answers and the correct question numbers in my mysqli code below so that it inserts those Answers and Question Numbers in the "Question" and "Answer" Tables?

Below I have set up the mysqli/php code, but it needs retweaked so it can insert the answers and the relevant question numbers correctly.

```
$i = 0;
$c = count($_POST['numQuestion']); //count number of rows

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

$questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (QuestionId) 
    VALUES (?)";


    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

$insert->bind_param("i", $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();

        $lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;

         $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (QuestionId, Answer) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

      if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }  


    $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $lastID, $_POST['value'][$i]);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insertanswer->close();

}
```

I have done a var_dump($_POST) for the above scenario and this is what it outputs:

```
array(2) { 
            ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { 
                                        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
                                        [1]=> string(1) "2" 
                                       }
           ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details" 
           ["value"]=> array(4) { 
                                    ["answerARow"]=> string(1) "A" 
                                    ["answerCRow"]=> string(1) "C" 
                                    ["answerBRow"]=> string(1) "B" 
                                    ["answerERow"]=> string(1) "E" 
                                } 
        }
```

I am receiving 2 errors which are identical:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (23000/1048): Column 'Answer' cannot
>   be null in /.../ on line 257  Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute():
>   (23000/1048): Column 'Answer' cannot be null in /.../ on line 257

UPDATE:

I have updated fiddle to include the multi-dimensional array, sorry I forgot to put it in but the line of code for this is below:

```
var $newBtn = $(("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this, " + gQuestionIndex + ");' />").replace('%s',$this.is(':visible')?'inline-block':'none')).attr('name', "value[" + gQuestionIndex + "][]").attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id')+'Row');
```

My suggestion is to use a multi-dimensional array in this format: value[n][], where n is the question number. With this new setup, you should end up with the following input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" value="A" name="value[1][]">
<input type="hidden" value="B" name="value[1][]">
<input type="hidden" value="A" name="value[2][]">
<input type="hidden" value="C" name="value[2][]">
<input type="hidden" value="E" name="value[2][]">
```

Note that the selected value is encoded in the value attribute. The name attribute only contains the question to which the value belongs.

Comment: It seems like the post does not have all the answers. Additionally, there is no relation between the posted answers and the posted question id. Can you explain the post logic you are using?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders To be honest what I tried to do was count the number of questions to retrieve the question number and then for each counted row, display the array of answers for each counted row. But obviously this is not working. The best way I believe but I need help on this is that when you select an answer button, it displays a text input showing the answer's value. Each text input involves a a name attribute which contains a multidimensional array where it will state what the answer value is and the question number it belongs to like so `value[n][]`. You can check this out in the jsfiddle

Comment: `(1, 2) VALUES (1, 2, 3)` - one of these things is not alike, one of these things is not quite the same.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders `value[n][]` where n is the question number and the answer's id is displayed in `[]`

Comment: Please don't use a JSfiddle link in the course of your problem, if that link dies, your question becomes useless.  Try to pare your problem down to its bare essentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the $POST does not have all the information, i suggest you to change the post structure to relation the question to the answer, something like this:

```
array(2) { 
            ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { 
                                        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
                                        [1]=> string(1) "2" 
                                       }
           ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details" 
           ["question_1"] => array(2) {
                                        [0] => string(1) "A"
                                        [1] => string(1) "C"
                                      }
           ["question_2"] => array(2) {
                                        [0] => string(1) "A"
                                        [1] => string(1) "B"
                                        [2] => string(1) "E"
                                      }
        }
```

Now, if the post would have that structure, you could do something like this to insert the data:

```
$numQuestionArray = $_POST["numQuestion"];

for($i =0; $i < count($numQuestionArray);$i++)
{
    $questionId = $numQuestionArray[$i];

    $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (QuestionId) VALUES (?)";

    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

    $insert->bind_param("i", $questionId);

    $insert->execute();

    if ($insert->errno) {
      // Handle query error here
    }

    $insert->close();

    $lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $questionAnswerPostStr = "question_".$questionId;

    $answerArray = $_POST[$questionAnswerPostStr];

    for($j =0; $j < count($numQuestionArray);$j++)
    {
        $answer = $numQuestionArray[$j];

        $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (QuestionId, Answer) VALUES (?, ?)";

        if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
          // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        }  

        $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $lastID, $answer);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insertanswer->close();
    }
}
```

However, i still think the question_id should be auto incremented on the table instead of inserting the $POST value.

Comment: HI, I tried your method but I am still getting this structure: `array(2) {  ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" }  ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details" ["value"]=> array(3) { ["answerARow"]=> string(1) "A" ["answerCRow"]=> string(1) "C" ["answerERow"]=> string(1) "E" } }`

Comment: The method will not work with this structure, it only work with the proposed structure. You have to change your script to act differently.

Comment: I wanted to know if you saw my comment below the question on how I am retrieving each answer and question number, couldn't that work? Have you seen the fiddle?

Comment: I did, but I really don't understand how that could work, and looking at your code, it would only insert 2 answers because the loop iterates in the number of questions. And, i have no idea how to retrieve a questions answer with that structure. Although i can be just missing something. So, you can either try my method or updating your question explaining (with code) how you would retrieve all the answers from a given question, for example.

Comment: I update fiddle, sorry I forgot to include a line of code in the fiddle of the multi-dimensional array. I included an UPDATE section in my question explaining on how I want the multi-dimentional array retrieve the answers and the question numbers associated with each answer